# Is ノシ considered 絵文字?

Tags: culture

My friend ended a letter thusly:

> あとでノシ

ノシ symbolizes a waving arm. Is this considered  絵文字 or does it have a different name?

Comment: This question is trivial. And it is not helpful. As Chocolate comments, if you want to call it, you can. If you don't want to, you can not to.

Comment: I learned that it is called both things so it was helpful to me. I apologize if you were offended or in any way put in a bad mood by the triviality of this question.

Comment: I was not offended at all. I just felt that it could be either way or the other, and does not matter. Never mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nico Nico](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B7) actually calls it 顔文字.  (And so do other places like [here](http://www.relief.jp/itnote/archives/001837.php).)

**Edit**: There is, perhaps, some crossover, but 絵文字 more broadly refers to things like [pictograms](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%94%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0) (pictures with meaning), while 顔文字 refers to...well, [顔文字](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A1%94%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97) (characters put together to make faces).

Comment: but it's not a face :/     ~thanks

Comment: [Chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1111154146) actually suggests that the face part of （＾－＾）ﾉｼ just gets omitted.

Comment: Some call it 顔文字 and others call it 絵文字　http://imiimiimi.seesaa.net/article/184478993.html　http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/1507390.html